# How to give background color to image using CSS in ReactJS?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Currently, I am trying to apply an on-hover overlay to the `<img />` like this:

```
const [hover, setHover] = useState(false);

        <img
          src={image}
          alt={alt}
          loading="lazy"
          onMouseOver={() => { setHover(true) }}
          onMouseOut={() => { setHover(false) }}
          style={{ zIndex: hover && 1,
                   transform: hover && 'scale(1.2, 1.2)', 
                   boxShadow: hover && '20px 20px 15px -4px #000000',
                   backgroundColor: hover && 'red',
                   transition: hover ? '0.5s' : '0.5s' }} />
```

However, I realized that the `backgroundColor` will be covered by the `img` itself. Is there any way to apply an overlay to the `<img />` with `backgroundColor` or other styling props using inline styling? I have seen many tutorials, but all of them are using `css` styling. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try to write your code right this?

```
<img
        src={image}
        alt={alt}
        loading="lazy"
        onMouseOver={() => {
          setHover(true);
        }}
        onMouseOut={() => {
          setHover(false);
        }}
        style={
          hover
            ? {
                zIndex: 1,
                transform: 'scale(1.2, 1.2)',
                boxShadow: '20px 20px 15px -4px #000000',
                backgroundColor: 'red',
                transition: '0.5s',
              }
            : { transition: '0.5s' }
        }
      />
```

Comment: yes, I can wirte the code like this, looks cleaner, still it won't work with the backgroundColor

Comment: that's img tag, so it's impossible to apply background color.
try to wrap img with div tag and apply bg color on the div